# angular header component reload after rout load

Tags: angular

i need to refresh header component after the user successfully log into the system. because i need to check user token null or not. I called that function inside the ngOninit() function. Please check my below header component code

```
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  newUserMenu = true;
  loginUserMenu = false;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private routers: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
this.isTokenAvailabe();
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.routers.navigate(['/login']);

  }

isTokenAvailabe() {
  console.log(this.authService.getJWTToken() );
  if (this.authService.getJWTToken() === null) {
    this.newUserMenu = true;
  } else {

    this.newUserMenu = false;
    this.loginUserMenu = true;
  } 

}

}
```

My problem is, isTokenAvailabe() function did not update. because that header component not reload or refresh. Therfore ngOnInit() function not load. How i update it?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Try `BehaviourSubject` to emit the `login` event. Subscribe for the same event from header component, or wherever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `BehaviourSubject` `Observable`. That allows you to push latest value to another component and in another component you will be subscribing(listening for change) to update the value.

In your `service.ts` you can do like this

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
public currentMessageSubscriber = this.messageSource.asObservable();


notify(message: any) {
  this.messageSource.next(message)
}
```

And in your `login.component.ts` you can call `notify()` in `login` `api` response like this

```
this.dataService.login(loginObject).subscribe(res=>{
    this.dataService.notify({isRefresh : true});
})
```

Finally inside your header.component.ts you can subscribe for getting update in `ngOnInit` like this

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.__dataService.currentMessageSubscriber.subscribe((data : any)=>{
   if(data.isRefresh ){
      this.isTokenAvailabe();
    }
 }) 
}
```

In this way when you receive `login` response so instantly you will notify another component that hey check for the token. And inside your `header.component.ts` you can subscribe for getting the msg to update instantly.

Comment: That's the idea indeed, but I don't like the fact that this is a generic notification. If the OP is only interested in receiving a notification when the user is logged, then he should only be notified about login/logout actions, not every single call to the notify method. Plus it doesn't take advantage of typescript types, that's weird to have a BehaviorSubject initialized with a string and use this subject to send objects...

Comment: So what's your suggestion for this? what one can do to prevent from getting notified each time ?

Comment: I'd suggest using a dedicated BehaviorSubject for authentication actions that would be called on login/logout events, rather than a generic BehaviorSubject that could be called with any parameter value and by any service. Your code seems more appropriate for something like logging events or showing toasters or something like that

Comment: @Carrm yes your suggestion will be helpful. Thanks :)